# Multiple statements inside a while loop

Tags: while-loop

I just found out that if i give while(i<=3,j<=10), then both the condition are evaluated but the loop exits only if the second condition is false. Can someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: What language are you asking about?

Comment: In C language,Gnu C compiler

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language, but you probably need to use an AND operator (possibly `&&`) to include both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator evaluates all supplied expressions but only returns the value of the last expression.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator